# crear un sp que reciba los parametros necesarios para ingresar un nuevo elemento en "x" tabla, pero que el nombre del nuevo elemento no se duplique

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi duda es como comparar en el if, la variable que creé llamada @name con el atributo de la tabla que se llama Name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En verdad es bastante sencillo:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Sales.Store WHERE Name = @name)
BEGIN
    SELECT '[nombre de tienda existente]';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Sales.Store
    VALUES(@entityID, @name, @salespersonID, @demographics, @rowguid, @modifieddate);
END
```

La próxima vez, por favor postea el código dentro de la pregunta, en vez de una imagen.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias @Lamak, si me sirvio, y no mas imagenes, solo una duda porque en el primer select le pones el numero 1?

Comment: @m3nt0r1337 es simplemente una forma de hacer notar que el resultado no es lo importante, sino que chequear la existencia de la fila. Podría haber usado `SELECT *` o cualquier otra cosa, pero `SELECT 1` es una convención bastante usada el momento de usar `EXISTS` por el motivo que te comenté

Comment: ya entendí, muchas gracias, hoy aprendí algo nuevo, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Otras 2 alternativas a tener en cuenta para cuidar la consistencia de los datos, sobre todo si este sp no es el único punto de entrada de datos a la misma:

1) Crear una restricción unique sobre el campo Name de la tabla Sales.Store

```
ALTER TABLE Sales.Store  ADD CONSTRAINT UK_Name UNIQUE (Name)
```

Y despues manejar el error con un Bloque Try Catch.

2) Crear un trigger sobre la tabla para controlar que no se repita el valor Name